# django finding ga.html to add Google Analytics

Tags: python, html, django, google-analytics

```
django/
    db.sqlite3
    helloworld/
        __init__.py
        context_processors/
            __init__.py
            google_anlytics.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    manage.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        migrations/
        models.py
        templates/
            polls/
                home.html
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    templates/
        ga.html
```

I am following this article to add google analytics to my django http://www.nomadblue.com/blog/django/google-analytics-tracking-code-into-django-project/

1. ive added `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID` and `GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DOMAIN` to `helloworld/settings.py`
2. Ive added the following to

hellowworld/context_processors/google_analytics.py

```
from django.conf import settings

def google_analytics(request):
    """
    Use the variables returned in this function to
    render your Google Analytics tracking code template.
    """
    ga_prop_id = getattr(settings, 'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID', False)
    ga_domain = getattr(settings, 'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DOMAIN', False)
    if not settings.DEBUG and ga_prop_id and ga_domain:
        return {
            'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID': ga_prop_id,
            'GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DOMAIN': ga_domain,
        }
    return {}
```

3. Then, I added `'helloworld.context_processors.google_analytics.google_analytics'`, to `helloworld/settings.py`
4. I added ga.html in templates

   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
     (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
     m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
     })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

     ga('create', '{{ GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID }}', '{{ GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DOMAIN }}');
     ga('send', 'pageview');
5. I've made sure my django project acn see the templates dir

   TEMPLATES = [
       {
           'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
           'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
           'APP_DIRS': True,
6. I want to add the following to polls/templates/polls/home.html

   {% if GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID %}
     {% include "path/to/your/ga.html" %}
   {% endif %}

QUESTION:

Now on the second line it says `"path/to/your/ga.html"`
I am not sure what to put there.

is it `../../../templates/ga.html?`

Answer (score 1):

I just put

```
{% if GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_PROPERTY_ID %} 
    {% include "ga.html" %} 
{% endif %}
```

and it found it